# What Windows registry key holds the path to the Chrome browser .exe

Tags: windows, google-chrome, registry, registrykey

I want to check to see if Chrome is installed (on Windows XP+) and create a shortcut to Chrome to launch a specific website (that requires Chrome).

What Registry key has the Path to the Chrome .exe?

I think it's this (just from looking @ a Chrome install on Win xp and 7):

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Chrome.exe
```

This works on Windows XP and Windows 7 (and according to an answer below, Windows 8 and 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Chrome.exe
```

This path is also valid on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1, so I suspect that it'll work 99% of the time. Keep in mind that these registry entries are not technically 100% reliable.  You could also check here for 64-bit Windows. You shouldn't need the Wow6432Node node for 32-bit Windows.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome
```

There is a DisplayIcon value there that points to the Chrome icon. Just remove the index from the end of the path (ie. remove the ,0).